# Can I access dynamic route name in next.js middleware?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, middleware

I have a route at `/:username`.

In my `_middleware.ts` file I would like do do something like this

```
export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const isDynamicRoute = req.nextUrl.pathname === "/[username]";
  
  if (isDynamicRoute) {
    return undefined
  }

  // handle other routes...
}
```

The issue is that I can't seem to access this dynamic route name in the middleware. I see `/test` as the pathname instead of `/[username]`.

When I log the `request` I see what I'm looking for, but it is inside a `[Symbol(internal request)]` key (along with a separate symbol key that includes the real pathname). Is it possible to access this value reliably in the middleware file? Or do I need to handle this logic in `_app.ts`? (see log below)

```
  [Symbol(internal request)]: {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: BaseHeaders [Headers] { [Symbol(map)]: [Object] },
    method: 'GET',
    referrer: 'about:client',
    redirect: 'follow',
    url: NextURL {
      href: '/test',
      origin: '',
      protocol: '',
      username: '',
      password: '',
      host: '',
      hostname: '',
      port: '',
      pathname: '/test',
      search: '',
      searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
      hash: ''
    }
  },
  [Symbol(internal request)]: {
    cookieParser: [Function: cookieParser],
    geo: {},
    ip: undefined,
    page: { name: '/[username]', params: [Object] },
    url: NextURL {
      href: '/test',
      origin: '',
      protocol: '',
      username: '',
      password: '',
      host: '',
      hostname: '',
      port: '',
      pathname: '/test',
      search: '',
      searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
      hash: ''
    }
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't `req.page.name` return what you're looking for?

Comment: wow you are right. I got confused by what was logged, and that `req.page` didn't show up when I logged `Object.keys(req)`.

This seems to work though! Thanks

Comment: yes, this normal behavior, Object keys defined with symbols won’t show up with Object.keys()

Comment: @juliomalves `req.page.name` has been removed on next 12.2 so unfortunately the question is very relevant again

Comment: @Daniel That's true. But for OP's scenario, v12.2 introduces a [`matcher` configuration](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware#matcher) that can be used to run the middleware on specific paths, which can be used instead of checking for the page name.

Comment: @juliomalves True, we were using it to send performance metrics per dynamic route but from what I understand - there's no way to get the dynamic path on 12.2

Comment: yes this is become an issue again

Comment: Here is the doc reference from next js. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/middleware-request-page#possible-ways-to-fix-it They actually removed 1 prop from Next request but added a way to replace deprecated api. Check it out and let me know if u can get it else i will cover it as full in answer to this question